# Is there a css rendering engine in php?

Tags: php, css

I would like to render all css properties in a HTML DOM. The goal is to know what is the display size of elements once rendered in a browser.
Is there any way to do this exclusively in php ? (i do not want to use external rendering engine as phantomjs for example, as it is too heavy)

The goal is to determine which texts are the bigger in order to add a rule in automatic data extractor engine. (final goal to determine automatically what are price and title xpaths in a e-shop product page)

thanks

Comment: Extremely unlikely, as this would necessitate a full HTML renderer. You may be able to run a headless browser on the server and interact with that from within PHP, but it's likely to be very complex.

Comment: 'once rendered in a browser' At that phase PHP is dead and gone. :P

Comment: Every browser renders differently. Also, browser settings will cause text to be bigger than defined in CSS.

Comment: You're trying to determinate the meaning of a data in HTML using th display style. So even if such tool could exist (which I doubt as you would still have to define a lot of browser/user-dependant settings), it would be very hazardous...

Comment: You may want to try posting a question about your original data extraction problem and see if the community can suggest alternative solutions. I'm not sure what you mean by "render CSS properties." Do you mean that you just want to know what properties will apply for a given element?

Comment: Bartdude, you're right, there still will be a human visual check, but checking only takes 3 seconds, fixing would take about 20 secs. That is 17 secs saved when the rule works. Multiplied by XXX that is a lot

What i would like it to know for a specific text is the font-size property (1em, 12px ...)

Comment: Users may even change the DPI of fonts on their machine, so how do you expect to know how a page is rendered? The best you could do is so far away from *easy* that I won't even suggest it.